# Start-up problem on 13.04

Tags: startup

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 on an Acer V3-571 
This has happened to me a few times. The PC stays irresponsive for about a minute and i have no opcion but to unplug it and beg for it to start correctly next time. Any clues? any suggestion on how to act when that happens? Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Any help will be wellcomed, for example, what is this "call trace" thing? How should I get information out of it? any suggestions on further readings? What other solution instead of unplugging the equipment when ubuntu freezes or becomes irresponsive. Thank you!

Comment: The same happens to my 13.04, but only about 1 of 10 boots, and only since I upgraded to kernel 3.8.0.19. I could not extract anything useful from the kernel panic trace nor the log files, however I think it's a bug in one of the kernel modules.

Comment: I also found this thread at launchpad that confirms that it's a known scenario... https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1175660

Comment: Seems like the kernel version 3.9 solves the problem. I'm going to install it, thank you for the link.

Comment: You're wellcome! Let me know if it solves the original issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using the kernel version 3.9 for raring, and the crashes are really gone.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.9-raring/